# How to display all columns of the datatype DATE when one column is actually a date and others are just time?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-date-functions, sqldatetime

I am learning SQL and using Oracle SQL Developer.
I have a table that contains the following columns

1. FlightDate
2. DepartureTime
3. ArrivalTime

I have inserted values using either

```
TO_DATE('10:45', 'hh24:mi')
```

or

```
TO_DATE('20/10/2000', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

When I do a SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME, the DepartureTime and ArrivalTime display a date (which I have not entered). How do I display the date in the first column and time in the other 2 columns?

I have tried
`

```
SELECT to_char(DepartureTime, 'HH24:MI' ) AS Departure
        to_char( ArrivalTime, 'HH24:MI' ) AS Arrival
  FROM FLIGHT;
```

`
Although the above statement displays the right values, I want to write a statement to output all the columns (because the actual table has more than 3 columns), but in the format explained above - a date for FlightDate and time for DepartureTime and ArrivalTime.

Comment: Oracle doesn't have a time data type, so you may use either date (which is actually a datetime) for both departure and arrival (which is very clear) or use interval day to second for times (that allows arithmetics without additional type conversions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data type that consists of 7 bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It **ALWAYS** has all of those components and it is **NEVER** stored in any particular (human-readable) format.

Therefore, if you have a `DATE` it will always be both a date and a time.

---

If you only want to store the date component of a date then you will need to use the entire date but could add a constraint to ensure the time is always midnight.

If you want to store a time without a date then you can either:

1. Use a `DATE` data type and just set the time component (and ignore the default values of the date component); or
2. Use an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type.

For example, your table could be:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  FlightDate    DATE
                CONSTRAINT table_name__flightdate__chk CHECK (flightdate = TRUNC(flightdate)),
  DepartureTime INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND(0) NOT NULL,
  ArrivalTime   INTERVAL DAY(1) TO SECOND(0) NOT NULL
);
```

Or, you could simplify your table to:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  Departure DATE NOT NULL,
  Arrival   DATE NOT NULL
);
```

and not worry about having separate dates and times.

Comment: Could you please provide the statement to insert, for example, 10:45 when using `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` without long precisions?

Comment: @Vonec `INSERT INTO table_name (flightDate, DepartureTime, ArrivalTime) VALUES (DATE '2022-11-25', INTERVAL '12:34' HOUR TO MINUTE, INTERVAL '1 02:15' DAY TO MINUTE);` or more options in this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/My6shfZA)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to alter session's NLS and affect *all* `DATE` datatype columns at once. Here's how:

Sample table and some data:

```
SQL> create table flight
  2    (id             number,
  3     flight_date    date,
  4     departure_time date,
  5     arrival_time   date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into flight values (1, to_date('10:45', 'hh24:mi'), to_date('20/10/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), sysdate);

1 row created.
```

This is what **my** database returns as a result:

```
SQL> select * From flight;

        ID FLIGHT_DA DEPARTURE ARRIVAL_T
---------- --------- --------- ---------
         1 01-NOV-22 20-OCT-00 24-NOV-22
```

Now, modify format to something else:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_Format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:Mi';

Session altered.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From flight;

        ID FLIGHT_DATE      DEPARTURE_TIME   ARRIVAL_TIME
---------- ---------------- ---------------- ----------------
         1 01.11.2022 10:45 20.10.2000 00:00 24.11.2022 21:17

SQL>
```

---

This is a SQL*Plus example, but the same works in SQL Developer as well.

Alternatively, open SQL Developer's **Preferences** (in "Tools" menu), search for "NLS" and enter **Date Format** you want.

Comment: So Oracle inserts the first day of the current month by default in Flight_Date? Is there any way to get rid of '01.11.2022 ' from Flight_Date?

Comment: You can insert actual date value; but - if you meant to entirely get rid of it, then the answer is **no** because there's no TIME datatype in Oracle, while DATE always contains both date and time part (up to seconds). If you need better precision, use TIMESTAMP datatype which lets you enter fractional seconds as well (along with date part, of course).

Answer (score 0):

The question *"When I do a SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME, the DepartureTime and ArrivalTime display a date (which I have not entered). How do I display the date in the first column and time in the other 2 columns?"* as I understand tells that DepartureTime and ArrivalTime columns are populated with date and time (as it is quite usual). I assume that your data looks something like here:

```sql
WITH
    flights (FLIGHT_OPERATOR, FLIGHT_FROM, FLIGHT_TO, DEPARTURE, ARRIVAL, SOME_OTHER_COL) AS
        (
            Select 'Vueling', 'Barcelona', 'Paris', To_Date('01.11.2022 10:45', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),   To_Date('01.11.2022 12:30', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 'Some other stuff' From Dual Union All
            Select 'RyanAir', 'Barcelona', 'Dublin', To_Date('01.11.2022 11:10', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),   To_Date('01.11.2022 13:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 'Some other stuff' From Dual Union All
            Select 'KLM', 'Barcelona', 'Amsterdam', To_Date('01.11.2022 20:10', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),   To_Date('01.11.2022 23:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 'Some other stuff' From Dual Union All
            Select 'Lufthansa', 'Barcelona', 'Frankfurt', To_Date('01.11.2022 23:25', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'),   To_Date('02.11.2022 02:20', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 'Some other stuff' From Dual 
        )
```

Selecting all from table looks, probably, like below:

| FLIGHT_OPERATOR | FLIGHT_FROM | FLIGHT_TO | DEPARTURE | ARRIVAL | SOME_OTHER_COL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Vueling | Barcelona | Paris | 01-NOV-22 | 01-NOV-22 | Some other stuff |
| RyanAir | Barcelona | Dublin | 01-NOV-22 | 01-NOV-22 | Some other stuff |
| KLM | Barcelona | Amsterdam | 01-NOV-22 | 01-NOV-22 | Some other stuff |
| Lufthansa | Barcelona | Frankfurt | 01-NOV-22 | 02-NOV-22 | Some other stuff |

As the question was "How do I display the date in the first column and time in the other 2 columns?" I would say that you are looking for this:

```sql
Select 
    FLIGHT_OPERATOR, FLIGHT_FROM, FLIGHT_TO, 
    DEPARTURE, To_Char(DEPARTURE, 'hh24:mi') "DEPARTURE_TIME", 
    ARRIVAL, To_Char(ARRIVAL, 'hh24:mi') "ARRIVAL_TIME", 
    SOME_OTHER_COL
From
    flights
Order By 
    DEPARTURE, FLIGHT_OPERATOR
```

Result would be:

| FLIGHT_OPERATOR | FLIGHT_FROM | FLIGHT_TO | DEPARTURE | DEPARTURE_TIME | ARRIVAL | ARRIVAL_TIME | SOME_OTHER_COL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Vueling | Barcelona | Paris | 01-NOV-22 | 10:45 | 01-NOV-22 | 12:30 | Some other stuff |
| RyanAir | Barcelona | Dublin | 01-NOV-22 | 11:10 | 01-NOV-22 | 13:00 | Some other stuff |
| KLM | Barcelona | Amsterdam | 01-NOV-22 | 20:10 | 01-NOV-22 | 23:00 | Some other stuff |
| Lufthansa | Barcelona | Frankfurt | 01-NOV-22 | 23:25 | 02-NOV-22 | 02:20 | Some other stuff |

So, the Departure and Arrival columns containe both the date and the time. You can select whatever part of that DateTime structure you want. In this answer I didn't take any part for Departure and Arrival but the columns as a whole. Their display format is defined by NLS_DATE_FORMAT (you can format it using NLS or some other way of displaying date/time). I just extracted time parts for departure and arrival dates in separate columns (like in the question) as there could be some night flights with different dates of departure and arrival.
Regards...